asus rog flow x13 running ubuntu 22.04 wont wake up from suspend
what the title says - I m running 22.04 (fresh install a week ago) dual boot with win 10 and everything is running smoothly except the suspend.
When I try to suspend it the power button flashes slowly and I cannot wake up the laptop i unless if i hold the power button for >5sec. Funny story, if the laptop is connected to the charger the backlit keyboard is also slowly flashing but i still have the same problem and the laptop does not wake up.
i have already tried to change nvidia driver (open source instead of proprietary) and force the laptop to only use the integrated graphics but it did not help. In the past that had helped (with another laptop but not now).
here is the log of
journalctl --grep='suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'
any help will be greatly appreciated

mai22 10:03:05 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 10:03:05 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
-- Boot 3bb548ddcbac4926b5ba9f8b592d36b1 --


mai22 12:40:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 12:40:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend


mai22 14:02:40 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 ModemManager[738]:   [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend


mai22 14:02:44 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...


mai22 14:02:44 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 suspend[9088]: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:02:44 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 logger[9088]: <13>May 22 14:02:44 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:02:45 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1399]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch


mai22 14:02:46 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.


mai22 14:02:46 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.


mai22 14:02:46 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...


mai22 14:02:46 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd-sleep[9108]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...


mai22 14:02:46 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
-- Boot 6de0704e1b0f4480a803709b30cb0d3e --


mai22 14:03:51 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 14:03:52 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend


mai22 14:32:01 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 ModemManager[773]:   [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend


mai22 14:32:06 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...


mai22 14:32:06 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 suspend[7352]: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:32:06 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 logger[7352]: <13>May 22 14:32:06 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:32:07 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1432]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch


mai22 14:32:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.


mai22 14:32:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.


mai22 14:32:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...


mai22 14:32:08 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd-sleep[7370]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
-- Boot bb7b2cecb5d641269626a3f3e927b175 --


mai22 14:33:18 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 14:33:18 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend


mai22 14:56:05 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 ModemManager[745]:   [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 suspend[11592]: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 logger[11592]: <13>May 22 14:56:09 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 systemd-sleep[11596]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...


mai22 14:56:09 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
-- Boot 650b0d25779d413391089ca23e5bc289 --


mai22 14:57:31 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 14:57:31 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
-- Boot 73e3aeb6de314250aaecedfa92866985 --


mai22 14:58:40 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 14:58:40 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
-- Boot 981aea3522714aa68e9ea8710a253f7a --


mai22 15:01:05 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 15:01:05 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
-- Boot bec77b167f59438da80e57ddf06376a4 --


mai22 16:30:22 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai22 16:30:22 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
-- Boot 93f50ec86bf440499ef34c8adc874327 --


mai23 08:25:45 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend


mai23 08:25:45 dhjah-ROG-Flow-X13 kernel: nvme 0000:08:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend

